# Hovering over one element effecting multiple classes merging or cascading

Tags: css

I have this code

```
    .card:not(:hover) .movePrevCarousel{   /* Used to make the button appear, when mouse hover*/
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .card:not(:hover) .moveNextCarousel{   /* Used to make the button appear, when mouse hover*/
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

Is there a way I can merge this together, instead of wrting it two times?

I have tried

```
    .card:not(:hover) .movePrevCarousel , .moveNextCarousel{   /* Used to make the button appear, when mouse hover*/
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

and it didn't work

Comment: share your html code, probably we can do something like `.card:not(:hover) > * {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot merge it but you can use multiple selectors for the same change

```css
.card:not(:hover) .movePrevCarousel,
.card:not(:hover) .moveNextCarousel {
  /* Used to make the button appear, when mouse hover*/
  opacity: 0;
}
```

If you were using a css pre-processor (like [less](http://lesscss.org/), [sass](https://sass-lang.com/)) you would be able to do

```css
.card:not(:hover) {
  .movePrevCarousel,
  .moveNextCarousel {
    /* Used to make the button appear, when mouse hover*/
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

which would produce the same result